# DB connection works without JNDI, doesn't work with it

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jndi

DB connection is successful when I create a connection within my application via DriverManager, but not when I setup the connection in the container via JNDI (java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver).

The connector J bin jar is in $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

**Stack:**

Tomact 8.5.5

MySQL Community Server 5.7.15

MySQL Connector/J 5.1.39

Java 8.xx

**$CATALINA_HOME/lib:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  989497 May  4 13:11 mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar

-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   18111 Sep 15 15:37 annotations-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   53138 Sep 15 15:37 catalina-ant.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  118471 Sep 15 15:37 catalina-ha.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   74730 Sep 15 15:37 catalina-storeconfig.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  268821 Sep 15 15:37 catalina-tribes.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089 1579678 Sep 15 15:37 catalina.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089 2393390 Sep 15 15:37 ecj-4.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   81438 Sep 15 15:37 el-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  163078 Sep 15 15:37 jasper-el.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  585489 Sep 15 15:37 jasper.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   26752 Sep 15 15:37 jaspic-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   61656 Sep 15 15:37 jsp-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  244276 Sep 15 15:37 servlet-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   10504 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  746028 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-coyote.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  251072 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-dbcp.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   65829 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-i18n-es.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   39545 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   42114 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  137738 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-jdbc.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   33871 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-jni.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  205530 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-util-scan.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  128849 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-util.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089  209672 Sep 15 15:37 tomcat-websocket.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 Foo 1049089   36662 Sep 15 15:37 websocket-api.jar
```

**Tomcat Server.xml extract:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/DB" 
               auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="root" password="admin" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>


    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation with the JSSE engine. When
         using the JSSE engine, the JSSE configuration attributes must be used.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation. When using the
         APR/native implementation or the OpenSSL engine with NIO or NIO2 then
         the OpenSSL configuration attributes must be used.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**Application web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>liquibase.changelog</param-name>
        <param-value>changelog.sql</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>liquibase.datasource</param-name>
        <param-value>java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>liquibase.host.includes</param-name>
        <param-value>localhost</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>liquibase.onerror.fail</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/DB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LiquibaseServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sandbox</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LiquibaseServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**This works:**

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent to
     * the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?" + "user=root&password=admin");
        if (conn != null) {
            return "Got it!";
        } else
            return "ERR";
    }
}
```

**This Doesn't:**

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent to
     * the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() throws Exception {

    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/DB");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn != null) {
            return "Got it!";
        } else
            return "ERR";
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>root cause</b></p><pre>org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>root cause</b></p><pre>java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
        org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167)
        org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
        org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
        com.sandbox.MyResource.getIt(MyResource.java:33)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>root cause</b></p><pre>java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
        org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
        org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
        org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
        com.sandbox.MyResource.getIt(MyResource.java:33)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
100  9239    0  9239    0     0  34864      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 37104rors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.5 logs.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.5</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you provide all the `server.xml` contents?

Comment: Updated with full server.xml

Comment: You need to make sure that the database driver class is available for the Tomcat Common class loader ($CATALINA_HOME/lib). If it is ok then you can try to move JNDI `<Resource>` definition under `<Host>` tag of servlet.xml.

Comment: @SergeyBespalov verified driver is there. Tried moving resource elem, but same result.

Comment: Also tried solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455532/how-to-correctly-configure-jndi-data-source-in-tomcat-8 with no luck